# Limits as a representation of the Dirichlet function

Tags: functions, rational-numbers, rational-functions, dirichlet-series

I read that the Dirichlet function ($1$ if Rational, $0$ else) can be written as:

$$ D(x)=\lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty} \cos^{2n}(m!\pi x)$$

What is the proof of that? Are those limits commutative? Is there any other closed formula for Dirichlet function? (With one limit? none?)

Thank you!

P.S:
The reason I try to understand Dirichlet function is because I need to write a function $f(a,b)$ that indicated if $a$ AND $b$ are rational. (The way of indication doesn't really matter, but $D(a)D(b)$ is the only idea I had in mind, yet, I need to write the function as closed one)

Comment: Well, I found this: http://www.bitsofpancake.com/math/explanation-of-the-dirichlet-function/ and understood the basics, but what I doesn't understand is why can't we write only one limit (n->infinity) and m=n ?

Comment: Anything? ... needs help